# RDS 2012R2: RD Connection Broker HA - cannot connect to SQL

Tags: sql-server, high-availability, remote-desktop-services, rds, database-connection

I have a brand new RDS environment I am trying to set up. I'm trying to follow this guide: https://msfreaks.wordpress.com/2013/12/09/windows-2012-r2-remote-desktop-services-part-1/ and have gotten pretty far, but I'm failing at the Configure RD Connection Broker for HA screen. This is the error I'm getting:

> The database specified in the database connection string is not
>   available from the RD Connection Broker server . Ensure
>   that the SQL Server is available on the network, the SQL Server Native
>   Client is installed on the RD Connection Broker server, and the RD
>   Connection Broker has write permissions to the database.

So far, this is what I have done and tried (in no particular order):

- Installed SQL Server Native Client on the RDS server (ran SQL Server 2014 setup, just installed the features "client tools connectivity" and "SQL client connectivity SDK"
- Verified in the SQL Server Configuration manager on both the RDS and the SQL server that TCP/IP is enabled
- Created an AD group called "RDS Connection Brokers", added the RDS servers, and gave the group dbcreator permissions in SQL server (out of desperation, I also attempted giving the group sysadmin privileges in SQL, but no go)
- Turned off the Windows Firewalls on both servers to test; no go
- Disabled AV on both servers temporarily to test; no go
- Rebooted both servers
- Tried creating a blank database of the correct name on the SQL server and ran the HA wizard again; no go
- Double-checked that native client is installed on both servers; appears to be installed

This is the database connection string I am attempting:

```
DRIVER=SQL Server Native Client 11.0;SERVER=SQLserver\SQLinstance;Trusted_Connection=Yes;APP=Remote Desktop Services Connection Broker;DATABASE=RDP_BROKER
```

Both servers are Win2012R2, and the SQL server is online and working, as we have other applications connecting to it. It IS a named instance, but according to my searches, this should still work. I've been searching google and serverfault, but pretty much everywhere says that what I'm doing should work. I feel like I am missing something basic.

Answer (score 1):

Great Article, Worked for me as well.

Changing the driver worked for me..

1. install ODBC driver on the RD connection broker - https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=50420
2. use this connection string:

   > DRIVER=ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server;SERVER=;Trusted_Connection=Yes;APP=Remote Desktop Services Connection Broker;Database=

Answer (score 0):

it **may** be required to enable the sql browser on the sql server to enable discovery of the instance from the client.

as you said other applications are accessing the sqlserver i assume that the firewall is opened and sql service is reachable via network.

*when multihomed, ensure that the sql service is reachable on the zone that is assigned to the network on which the rds gateways are located (may be public whereas other applications use an interface on domain zone).*

Comment: SQL Browser was already enabled... and yes for the firewall and SQL service being reachable via the network (I also disabled the firewall on both RDS & SQL servers just to test, as mentioned above). And yes, both servers are on the Domain network and are reporting correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Changing the driver worked for me..
1. install ODBC driver on the RD connection broker - https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=50420
2. use this connection string:

```
DRIVER=ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server;SERVER=<DB server, e.g. sql,1433>;Trusted_Connection=Yes;APP=Remote Desktop Services Connection Broker;Database=<DB Name>
```